# Php errors, cant find where

Tags: php

I have this file that I need help fixing the errors I am gettng. I checked and it seems fine, but something must be wrong. The errors are

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/info130/FA13/users/tmh233fa13/www/Test/posting_wall.php on line 62
```

and my php is listed below, both files.

Thanks!

Posting_wall.php file.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="post.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
/* [INFO/CS 1300 Project 3] index.php 
 * Main page for our app.
 * Shows all previous posts and highlights the current user's post, if any.
 * Includes a link to form.php if user wishes to create and submit a post.
 */ 

require('wall_database.php');

// Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];

$is_valid_post = true;
// Checking if a form was submitted
if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
  // Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']); 
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);  
  // Saving the current post, if a form was submitted
  $post_fields = array();
  $post_fields['name'] = $name;
  $post_fields['email'] = $email;
  $post_fields['message'] = $message;
  $post_fields['date'] = $date;

  $success_flag = saveCurrentPost($post_fields);
}

//Fetching all posts from the database
$posts_array = getAllPosts();

require('header.php');
?>
    <p><a href="form.php">Submit a Post</a></p>

    <?php
    if(isset($name)) {
      echo "<h3>Thanks ".$name." for submitting your post.</h3>";
    }
    ?>

    <p>Here are all the posts we have received.</p>
    <ul id="posts_list">
    <?php 

    // Looping through all the posts in posts_array
    $counter = 1;
    foreach(array_reverse($posts_array) as $post){
      $name = $post['name'];
      $email = $post['email'];
      $message = $post['message'];
      $date = $post['date'];
      if ($counter % 2==1)
        $li_class = "float-left";
      else
        $li_class = "float-right";

      echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
      // Add more details here
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Form.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var value;

    // "message" pattern : from 3 to 15 alphanumerical chars

    value = $('[name="message"]').val();
    if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}$/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "message".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // "name" pattern : at least 1 digit

    value = $('[name="name"]').val();
    if (!/\d+/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "name".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> <u>Daily Dorm News</u> <br> The best place to get your latest Dorm news </h1>
<form action="posting_wall.php" method="get">
<div id="container">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}" title="Letters and numbers only, length 3 to 15" required autofocus><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="20" required><br>

Post:<br>

<textarea rows="15" cols="50" name='message'></textarea>
</div>
Date this event took place: <input type="text" name='date' id="datepicker" required> <br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<p><a href="posting_wall.php">Posting Wall</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the HTTP POST lack the 'name' key.

The error is explicit, if you edit the php file and go to line 62, you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You never set $name, you set $username.

Copyed and clipped from your code:

> ```
> $username = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
>
> ...
>
> $post_fields['username'] = $name;
> ```

Comment: yes I did that since in my form, the name for the username field =name, or that does not matter?

Comment: You never set the varible $name

Comment: I tried it but no luck, not sure, its an easy fix im just a little lost. I updated the code in the OP to what I tried, but still no luck